# SDL Web 8.5 Translation Review Workflow - hide Translation Segments

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5, translation-manager

Using the default [Translation Review Workflow](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-0CE3454F-49BF-4325-AFC1-2051678CD9CF#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtranslation%2520review&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1528732038355&currentQuery=translation%2520review&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-FEF19899-77EB-4EC7-AD0E-B142F3164B5E&query=translation%2520review&scope=&filename=GUID-FEF19899-77EB-4EC7-AD0E-B142F3164B5E.xml&docid=GUID-FEF19899-77EB-4EC7-AD0E-B142F3164B5E&inner_id=&tid=d878bb6b-0973-41cd-a06b-34e0d5466e36&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false) I can see when a component is assigned to the Translation Review activity that a "Translation Segments" tab is available on the component GUI and in properties in XPM.

[image]

[image]

Once a user starts this activity, the Target Language fields are editable within this and a user can make changes so when they're finished, they can finish the activity by assigning to ACCEPT & these changes are sent back to TMS or REJECT with comments also visible in TMS.

Is it possible to hide or turn off this "Translation Segments"?

In our scenario we'd prefer for our reviewers to be able to view translations in context via XPM, start the review activity assigned to them (or their group) and then assign to REJECT adding comments - to indicate to TMS that changes are needed - not directly change any translations themselves.

If no changes are needed they assign to ACCEPT as before.

If not configurable, I'm thinking some kind of XPM GUI extension that only for these reviewers:

- turns off "Open in Form View", so they cant just circumvent XPM.
- hides the Translation Segment portion of the Properties window.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

A translation review is a standard Tridion workflow, so any trick that works in Tridion in general will work with translation review workflows. So if the users do not need write permission to the component at any time (they only do translation review), this can be achieved by only granting them read access to the content in Tridion - I believe they are still able to start and finish activities.

If they do require write permission to the item when it is not in translation then an extension can be written to:

1. Make the item read only (this will prevent the user from editing). Most likely it will be sufficient to set it as read-only if the segments are present without having to investigate the workflow step in details.
2. Remove the segments to prevent the segmented view from being displayed at all in CME/XPM. Do not do this without also implementing option 1 or you might end up with data out of sync.

A few tweaks with an appropriate sized hammer might be needed somewhere in case Tridion does not like reviewing read-only items, but I do not think this will be necessary.

The extension can be done in a few places:

- A TCM event handler changing the item after load. This must run after the Translation Manager extension to ensure the segments aren't inserted afterwards. Also allows server side checks to check requests bypassing the UI (requests going directly to the CoreService)- though that might not be a requirement in your case.
- An Anguilla DataExtender.
- JavaScript in an Anguilla extension - probably more complex and less likely to run without problems in a new version of Tridion, so I would go with one of the other two options if possible.

Comment: Do you mean "require write permission when the item *is in* translation"? If its not in translation then I dont need the extension.

Comment: So it sounds adding my reviewers to a read-only User Group could be the simplest action? They wouldn't be able to make any changes but they'd still be able to assign/start/finish the necessary activities of the Translation Review workflow?

Comment: Yes. This is what I expect to happen. I never tried assigning workflow activities to a user with read-only access, so it might be worth trying to make 100% sure. This is not translation specific by the way - it is standard workflow behavior you need to check.